# Cómo convertir un array en una matriz de PHP

Tags: php

Tengo esta matriz en PHP:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["IdPedido"]=> string(10) "PJSDJKSDKS" ["idarticulo"]=> string(9) "PSJASJDJC" } [1]=> array(2) { ["IdPedido"]=> string(9) "JSAKSDOWS" ["idarticulo"]=> string(8) "UANSYXHC" } [2]=> array(2) { ["IdPedido"]=> string(9) "ZZZZYYYYP" ["idarticulo"]=> string(12) "628492913823" } }
```

Me gustaría convertirlo en un array. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Por el momento he intentado este código:

```
 $DBchangesMS;
    $arrayCambiosMS=array();
    //IdPedido es key e idarticulo value
    foreach ($DBchangesMS as $key => $value) {
        if($key){
            $DBchangesMS=$key;
        }else{
            $DBchangesMS=$value;
        }

        var_dump($DBchangesMS);
        
    }
```

y el resultado que me devuelve es el siguiente:

```
array(2) { ["IdPedido"]=> string(10) "PJSDJKSDKS" ["idarticulo"]=> string(9) "PSJASJDJC" } int(1) int(2)
```

Parece que no voy mal, ya que los dos primeros datos sí me loas ha pasado de matriz a array, pero luego por ejemplo me pilla dos int (1, 2) que son los índices de las siguientes filas de la matriz, pero no me accede a los valores y no me los mete en el array.
He hecho otra prueba con este código:

```
    $DBchangesMS;
    $arrayCambiosMS=array();
    //IdPedido es key e idarticulo value
    foreach ($DBchangesMS as $key => $value) {
        if($value==["IdPedido"]){
            $arrayCambiosMS=$value["IdPedido"];
        }

        var_dump($arrayCambiosMS);
        
    }
```

El resultado es éste:

```
array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

Otra prueba de código que estoy haciendo:

```
    for ($i=0; $i < count($DBchangesMS[$i]); $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j < count($DBchangesMS[$i]["IdPedido"]); $j++) {
            if(!is_null($DBchangesMS[$i]["IdPedido"])){
                $arrayCambiosMS=$DBchangesMS[$i]["IdPedido"];
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($DBchangesMS[0]);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($DBchangesMS[1]);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($DBchangesMS[2]);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($DBchangesMS[0]["IdPedido"]);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($DBchangesMS[1]["IdPedido"]);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($arrayCambiosMS);
```

La salida de este código es la siguiente:

```
array(2) { ["IdPedido"]=> string(10) "PJSDJKSDKS" ["idarticulo"]=> string(9) "PSJASJDJC" }
array(2) { ["IdPedido"]=> string(9) "JSAKSDOWS" ["idarticulo"]=> string(8) "UANSYXHC" }
array(2) { ["IdPedido"]=> string(9) "ZZZZYYYYP" ["idarticulo"]=> string(12) "628492913823" }
string(10) "PJSDJKSDKS"
string(9) "JSAKSDOWS"
string(9) "JSAKSDOWS"
```

No sé en qué estoy fallando ni cómo puedo mejorar esto. En esta última salida de código al menos sí me está metiendo en el array de salida el segundo IDPedido (el del índice 1, no sé pq no me está metiendo el primero). Es un pequeño avance, pero quiero que me meta en el array TODOS los IdPedido del array de entrada. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pues la salida ya evidencia que es un array asociativo, ¿podrías ser mas claro?

Comment: Sí, a ver, yo ahora mismo tengo esa salida. Pues yo quiero a partir de esta matriz un array que te tenga la información de la siguiente forma: 

{"PJSDJKSDKS",
"PSJASJDJC",
"JSAKSDOWS",
""UANSYXHC"...
}

Comment: que formato es ese? no parece json ni tampoco un array estandar... Ten en cuenta que en PHP los arrays son siempre "asociativos" (en caso de no tener clave, se puede interpretar como claves numericas consecutivas)

Comment: ¿El formato que yo quiero sacar, te refieres? Pues un formato estándar de array en PHP (seguramente lo haya puesto mal).

Comment: sigo sin entenderlo. Lo unico que quieres hacer es sacar los valores que hay en las claves `idPedido`?

Comment: Exactamente. Tener un array de salida con los valores de cada IdPedido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta el comentario de que solo quieres obtener un array con los valores de idPedidos, podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
$arrayCambiosMS=array();
foreach ($DBchangesMS as $key => $value) {
    $arrayCambiosMS[] = $value['IdPedido'];
}
```

date cuenta que hay unos corchetes en la asignacion de arrayCambiosMS. Asi, por cada IdPedido que encuentres, se inserta el valor, como un elemento mas en el array.

Comment: Mil gracias por tu respuesta, funciona y me ha devuelto exactamente lo que quería. Sin embargo, te quiero preguntar una duda: ¿por qué funciona? Porque yo me liaba porque al ser una matriz asociativa tenemos distintas posiciones 00, 10, 20, 01, 11, 21 etc... Y yo decía si hago un foreach, en este caso... value es el valor correspondiente, pero key, ¿cuál sería? Entonces no sabía cómo hacerlo con un foreach. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: cuando defines un array sin indices, las claves por defecto empiezan con 0,1,2,... Lo que tenias antes era un array asociativo. Solo he recorrido tu array (el foreach te ayuda en ese recorrido mucho, definiendo el $key y $value), lo unico que en este caso no he utilizado $key.

Comment: Es decir, que tu foreach ha ido recorriendo 00, 10, 11, 01, 11 etc. sin indicarle ni length como en un for ni indicarle índice (pese a ser un array asociativo), ¿no? No sabía que se podía hacer eso. Mil gracias :)

Comment: de hecho, esa es la gracia del foreach. Se basa internamente en que un array es un elemento iterable. por lo tanto, conoces los elementos que hay. Solo va pasando de uno en uno por todos los elementos. No se a que te refieres con lo de 00, 10, 11, 11...

Comment: 00, 10, 11...son las posiciones de la matriz. Fila 0, columna 0, fila 1, columna 0 etc.